# How to use the elasticseach java api for dynamic searches?

Tags: elasticsearch

So I'm trying to use elasticsearch for dynamic query building. Imagine that I can have a query like:

```
a = "something" AND b >= "other something" AND (c LIKE "stuff" OR c LIKE "stuff2" OR d BETWEEN "x" AND "y");
```

or like this:

```
(c>= 23 OR d<=43) AND (a LIKE "text" OR a LIKE "text2") AND f="text"
```

Should I use the QueryBuilder or the FilterBuilder, how do you match both? The official documentation says that for exact values we should use the filter approach? I assume I should use filters for equal comparisons? what about dates and numbers? Should I use the Filter or Query?

For the Like/Equals for the number/number problem I tried this:

```
@Field(type = String, index = FieldIndex.analyzed, pattern = "(\\d+\\/\\d+)|(\\d+\\/)|(\\d+)|(\\/\\d+)")
public String processNumber;
```

The pattern would deal with the structure number + slash + number, but also number and number + slash.

But when using either the term filter or the match_query I can't get only hits with the exact structure like 20/2014, if I type 20 I would still get hits on the term filter.

Answer (score 1):

Query is the main component when you search for something, it takes into consideration ranking and other features such as stemming, synonyms and other things. Filter, on the other hand, just filters the result set you get from your query.

I suggest that if you don't care about the ranking use filters because they are faster. Otherwise, use query.

Comment: What if you want exact values like you're using an equals (=)? versus LIKE comparisons?

Comment: If you are referring to = and LIKE operators in SQL, then queries in Elasticsearch is loosely similar to LIKE. However, Elasticsearch is much more capable and better. If you want to do exact match for text then look at phrase matching http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/phrase-matching.html

Comment: Thanks! This was helpful but how can i use a field so that i can compare as LIKE or EQUAL without having to mess with the mappings definition. If you put the index to not_analyzed then i can't seem to make match queries. considering this format "20/2014", i want to search as an exact value, meaning i write 20/2014, or i want to use a LIKE condition for 20, 20/,2014 or /2014. is this achievable?

Comment: Oh I think you are referring to a different thing. I think what you want is to tokenize your strings "20/2014" to be "20", "20/", "2014", "/2014" then you want the user to match these strings. Meaning when you get your strings, you want elasticsearch to treat your strings to this. This is called analyzing and tokenizing. Here is a link that can help you http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html

Comment: Hi! I assume i need to use the pattern, with a regex expression?

@Field(type =   String,index = FieldIndex.analyzed, pattern = "regex expression here?")
    public String   processNumber;